# Eclipse Luna SR2 Cannot Resolve Imports. Slow to Recognize

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using "Eclipse Luna SR2: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". I have a fairly large Java EE project. Alot of the packages have java classes with Imports to other packages and files, but I constantly get "Import xyz cannot be resolved". I compile and build using mvn clean and mvn install with not errors. Code works fine which is why I am linking this to an eclipse issue. Is there anyway to fix this problem in eclipse? Is it just working very slowly?

Please let me know if anyone has had a similar issue and how did you go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Comment: I experience slowness when eclipse is updating the maven dependencies and building the workspace.Check the maven setup (in Eclipse )to make sure if this is the case by default

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps in eclipse

Select the project -> Maven -> Update Project. This may your solve your problem.